# « Gugu » : signification

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Dans le [texte suivant](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1098?m=56465975#56465975) d'un utilisateur SFE (20goto) on trouve le terme « gugu ».

> Enfin j'ai compris pourquoi Pam Grier « marchait sans marcher » au début de la séquence d'ouverture de Jackie Brown (youtu.be/ivKGY-zAa1g) !! Mais je parlais pas d'un gugu de tapis roulant plat d'aéroport, c'est plus comme un train sans murs. Mais j'ai lu qu'il y en avait eu un bien récent qui allait bien vite (11km/h) mais il se brisait souvent et ils l'ont enlevé il y a 10 ans...

On ne trouve rien dans les dictionnaires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ça ressemble beaucoup à une réduction de [*gugusse*](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/gugusse) signifiant familièrement un « objet quelconque » au Québec, comme *bidule, truc* ou *machin* (Usito). Quand c'est déterminé par un nom (*...de tapis roulant plat d'aéroport*), ça se veut dépréciatif. L'idée c'est que le tapis roulant d'aéroport est sans commune mesure avec ce qu'était la « rue de l'Avenir », donc déprécier le premier va dans cette direction...